# Density with flat Fourier transform around the origin

Tags: fourier-transform

I am looking for a density function f on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (nonnegative function that integrates to 1) with compact support which Fourier transform is constant (equal to 1) on a neighbourhood of the origin: the requirements are

- $f\geq 0$
- $\int_{\mathbb R^2} f=1$
- $f(x)=0$ for $\|x\|\geq R$ for some $R>0$
- $\hat f(x)=1$ for $x\in B(0,\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon>0$

Equivalently I was looking for $g$ square integrable such that $g\star g=1$ around the origin, but not more luck on this one...

If you have an example on $\mathbb R^d$ I am also interested.

Edit: $f$ can be a distribution, but not the Dirac mass in 0 :)

Comment: I don't think it is possible to meet all conditions, because a natural answer would be to take the Fourier Transform of the characteristic function of interval $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ which is the **cardinal sine** function : 
$$f(x)= \frac{1}{a} \operatorname{sinc}(ax)$$
where $a$ is certain constant (depending on $\epsilon$, your definition of cardinal sine, and also on your definition of Fourier transform). **But** its support isn't bounded, which is a drastic condition.

Comment: A related class of functions are Mollifiers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier#Definition)

Comment: The problem of sinc is also that it takes negative values, I am still interested in an answer without the bounded support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't exists. The Fourier transform of any distribution with compact support is analytic, but analytic functions cannot be constant on a set with an acummulation point unless they are constant, but in that case $f$ would be a dirac mass, which you don't allow.

Comment: Right, thanks. Any idea if it could work without the bounded support assumption?